# Is Yarn WorkSpace and NPM package Same Thing

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I previously worked on NPM and know what is the structure of a package like, basically each project you are developing on would become a package after development is done and that can be published to NPM regsitry for share.

Recently I moved to a project that has Yarn as package manager, and certainly the whole project is a monorepo. I learned that the basic unit under yarn is **Workspace**. And I think a workspace is just as a project(a new package) developed in npm, as the fact under the root fold of the developed package(or in yarn it is workspace), there is a package.json file and a node_modules folder.

In such sense I think they(a package and workspace) are same thing, and also from yarn's [documentation on workspace](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces), it states:

> "A workspace is a specific named package ..."

I want to confirm if my reasoning is correct or not. Hope someone could shed lights to me. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's correct. Although i'm wondering the same as you at the moment... as in... are every workspaces meant to become npm packages, or could it be optional? like a way to organize code in packages without necessarily having to publish all separated items.